# Uploading AAB Bundle to AppCenter downloads an APK File?

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-app-center, android-app-bundle

I am converting my Android app from APK to AAB. However, when I uploaded the bundle.aab to AppCenter, the download was an APK? Shouldn't the download be a .AAB file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android OS can only install APKs. If you upload Android App Bundles to the Google Play Store, the Play Store then generates optimized APKs for your end users.

Microsoft's App Center on the other hand generates an unoptimized universal APK.

"When you distribute Android Application Bundle (AAB), App Center generates a universal APK, signs it with a generated signing key, and distributes it to a device."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'm glad I didn't do anything wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Same here. Try downloading in another browser. For me it downloads `.aab` on Safari but `.apk` on Chrome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).